# Empty request.POST on Django AJAX call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to send form data to one of my view. But I am getting empty request.POST

My ajax call is :

```js
ajaxSubmit = () =>{

    exam_type = document.getElementById('exam_type').value
    total_marks = document.getElementById('total_marks').value
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', "{% url 'addExamForm' %}", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
          alert("Success");
        } else {
            alert("Fail");
        }
      };
    request.send(JSON.stringify({"exam_type":exam_type,"total_marks":total_marks}));
}
```